# Laravel's Cashier-Paddle Not Working Locally?

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I've tried to use both ngrok and Expose with the Paddle Sandbox and while the subscription is being created perfectly in Paddle, on the Laravel side, I keep getting the same error:

> [2022-05-08 23:23:50] local.ERROR: openssl_verify(): supplied key
> param cannot be coerced into a public key {"exception":"[object]
> (ErrorException(code: 0): openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot
> be coerced into a public key at
> ~/vendor/laravel/cashier-paddle/src/Http/Middleware/VerifyWebhookSignature.php:71)

Is there a particular format the public key in .env needs to be in to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out. It turns out that when you're putting your PADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY in .env, you should include everything i.e.

```
PADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBiuqhiiG9w0BAQEFXAOCAg8AMIIjjgKCAraAyj/UyC89sqpOnpEZcM76
guppK9vfF7balLj87rE9VXq5...EAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this ( no need use -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

"MIICIjANBiuqhiiG9w0BAQEFXAOCAg8AMIIjjgKCAraAyj/UyC89sqpOnpEZcM76
guppK9vfF7balLj87rE9VXq5...EAAQ=="

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).